# Amazon S3 Copy and Rename file using REST API in Javascript/AJAX/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

I have a requirement to copy and rename some S3 media files (they will remain in the same bucket) upon request in my Javascript application. I believe the best way to this is to use the PUT Object - Copy described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

My question arises in how to construct the actual Ajax call to have this happen. I know how to specify the target file bucket and file name (such as `"x-amz-copy-source": "EXAMPLE_BUCKET/example.png"`) but how do I specify the source bucket and file name?

Is it part of the FormData, is it built into the url or does the key somehow represent it? Yes, I am new to S3 so forgive my lack of knowledge.

Here is what I have so far (I have not executed this but will later today):

```
  copyAndRename: function (url, newBucketAndFile, key, contentType, accessKey, region, policy, signature) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var date = moment().utc().format("YYYYMMDD");
        fd.append("key", key);   // Not sure if needed?
        fd.append("Content-Type", contentType);
        fd.append("x-amz-copy-source", newBucketAndFile);
        fd.append("acl", "private");
        fd.append("policy", policy);
        fd.append("x-amz-meta-tag", "");
        fd.append("x-amz-meta-uuid", "11111111111111");
        fd.append("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256");
        fd.append("X-Amz-Credential", accessKey + "/" + date + "/" + region + "/s3/aws4_request");
        fd.append("X-Amz-Date", date + "T000000Z");
        fd.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
        fd.append("X-Amz-Signature", signature);
        var success = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,   // Is this the bucket and file path?
            method: "PUT",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false
        }).done(function (result) {
            success = true;
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
            success = false;
        });
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you are building the request manually instead of using the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Comment: Er, surely the source object, not the target object, is in x-amz-copy-source. And the target object is the URI that you are invoking PUT on.

Comment: @Mark B That is the current pattern employed by the app, which I am adding to. Not sure why we went with a REST approach rather than a S3 SDK.

Comment: @jarmod Doh, brain freeze on that one. I will switch it and give the URI approach a try.